# Email is not sent in magento 1.9

Tags: php, email, magento

I am using **Magento 1.9.1.** I installed `magento` in my local machine. But email is not working here.

When a registered user place an order, email from admin is not sent. Also when Admin click the
 `Send Email` button from `Orders` section a message `The order email has been sent` is displayed, but email was not sent.

Also in `Email to a friend` section, I fill the `to` and `from` fields for send message. This also not working.

When I click `forget password` the mail is not sending to the corresponding mail id.

How can I make this working. Please help me...Any help is really appreciable..

Thanks.

Comment: Did you configure sendemail settings in php.ini for your local machine?? Which OS do you use?

Comment: @PavanKumar, How can i did this? I am using windows 8.1

Comment: Try this http://jesin.tk/using-sendmail-on-windows/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send email from your local machine you have to set up an email client. For that install the extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Instructions are provided in the screenshots of the extension. You just have to enter the email address here thats all.

With this you can semd email from local machine.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

More than possibly caused by the fact that you did not set the cron on your Magento.
Try to visit the page *cron.php* of your Magento, something like http://example.com/cron.php, **twice** and see if you get the email.

Magento is sending mail on a cron, to lighten the mail charge of the site.

Then visit [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507024119/http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) to understand cron in magento and to set your cron.

If you are on a *nix OS:

1. on your shell: `crontab -e`
2. inside this crontab: `*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh`
3. Save the crontab, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I dont think so it is due to the cronjob. He is using his local machine and he has to configure SENDMAIL settings in his php.ini file. This is the issue

Comment: mail() is working out of the box on [opinion based]good OS[/opinon based] so, yes maybe, but that can not be stated only with the information given.
What can be stated is : Magento does not work on all of his email function (as of 1.9) without the cronjob configured correctly and that is even on their site, in the beginning of the page I did link in my answer : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job **A few features in Magento require a script to be run periodically.**